# How to extract dot app(.app) mac file from a zip programmatically?

Tags: macos, zip, unity-game-engine, sharpziplib

I am working on a Unity project & facing an issue.
I have a zip file containing **mybuild.app** (mac) file.

I am using [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) to uncompress the zip file. Issue is, when lib uncompressing, it actually taking **mybuild.app** as a folder & create a directory with same name & its sub files & folders. After uncompressing **mybuild.app** is not being able to start.

I think the issue is with .app signature or something. I shouldn't extract .app file content separately.

Please tell me how can i get **mybuild.app** file from zip which actually works.

I am using Unity 3.5.6 on mac.

**Here is my code:**

```
using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(a_filePath)))
{
    ZipEntry theEntry;
    while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(theEntry.Name);

        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(theEntry.Name);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);

        // create directory
        if (directoryName.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Creating Director: " + directoryName);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
        }

        if (fileName != String.Empty)
        {
            string filename = a_extractPath;
            filename += theEntry.Name;
            Debug.Log("Unzipping: " + filename);
            using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(filename))
            {
                int size = 2048;
                byte[] fdata = new byte[2048];
                while (true)
                {
                    size = s.Read(fdata, 0, fdata.Length);
                    if (size > 0)
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(fdata, 0, size);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just add `.app` onto the end of the extracted directory?

Comment: @l'L'l, .app @ the end of dir name already there. But when i click on it. It keeps popping up & down in tray, but do not start.

Comment: that means the permissions on the executable probably needs to be chmod to 755.